# python index out of range when item in list is none

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting `IndexError: list index out of range` but I know where the problem is in the json I am mapping.

```
server_names_and_ips = [
            (x['virtualMachine']['name'], x['virtualMachine']['network']['publicIpAddresses'][0]['ipAddress']) for x in
            s if x['virtualMachine']['network']['publicIpAddresses'][0]['ipAddress'] is not None]
```

The problem is `x['virtualMachine']['network']['publicIpAddresses'][0]['ipAddress']` has a value you `[]` in one of the items returned. I tried to put the if condition in for it but that didnt work correctly. Is something wrong with how I wrote the if condition? The desired outcome who be...if it has `[]` dont add that item to list and move onto the next.

Comment: Share a sample json. As it is, the ask isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking if the list has any elements:

```
server_names_and_ips = [
        (x['virtualMachine']['name'], x['virtualMachine']['network']['publicIpAddresses'][0]['ipAddress']) for x in
        s if len(x['virtualMachine']['network']['publicIpAddresses']) > 0 and x['virtualMachine']['network']['publicIpAddresses'][0]['ipAddress'] is not None]
```